# HTTPS enabled Spring Boot App does not work when deployed on Beanstalk

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I enabled HTTPS for my APIs using local generated SSL key following the instructions in [Enable HTTPS in Spring Boot](https://drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/). The ssl settings are included in `application.properties`:

```
server.port=9443
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:server-keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=123456
server.ssl.keyAlias=server-keypair
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
```

It works with https when tested locally. Then I packaged it as a Jar and deployed on Amazon Beanstalk environment. When I hit endpoint `https://eb-env-url:9443/endpoint/`, it timed out without any specific error. The Beanstalk log does not show any request was made through to the server at all.

I read it somewhere that personal key may not work when deployed to cloud, but it should at least give me some security error that points to that direction. I suspect this may have to do with the environment configuration. I used to do HTTP only for the environment and did not make any changes to the config after switching to HTTPS. One of the environment variable is SERVER_PORT which is set to 5000. I am not sure if some changes need to made in the Beanstalk environment in order to make HTTPS work.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `SERVER_PORT` environment variable to your application port `9443`?

Comment: where you able to get this resolved? Thanks, WB

Comment: You can configure your instance in elastic beanstalk with the load balancer, cloud front and Route 53 to redirect the requests, follow the next documentation: [Requiring HTTPS for Communication Between CloudFront and Your Custom Origin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-cloudfront-to-custom-origin.html) and: [Create a Classic Load Balancer with an HTTPS Listener](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: Thanks for the post. What is the best practice storing SSL password In embedded tomcat spring boot applications？I see examples that all have those alias and password for a trustStore.jks defined in a properties file. What if we need to use Dockerfile to creat an image and deploy it to a kubernetes cluster? Any design patterns or suggestions? Thanks!